# wxPython gridbagsizer colour

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm testing with an application. 
Now I want to have a nice border around the mid panel, so it's embedded in another panel. 
However, when I want to add a gridbagsize in it and put static text components in it, it gets the colour of the main panel, not the midpanel. 
Obviously I'm doing something wrong...

Code:

```
    #Parent panel
    pnl = wx.Panel(self)
    pnl.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    midPan = wx.Panel(pnl)
    midPan.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')

    vbox.Add(midPan,wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 20)

    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10,5)
    #sizer.
    st1=wx.StaticText(pnl,label='TEST')
    sizer.Add(st1, pos=(1,1),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)
    midPan.SetSizer(sizer)
    #vbox.Add(sizer,wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 0)
    #draw application       
    pnl.SetSizer(vbox)
```

[image]

as you see, it looks like the sizer is added to the pnl instead of the midPan...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining your statictext as a child of the pnl rather than midPan

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", size=(360,100)):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, size)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        pnl.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        midPan = wx.Panel(pnl)
        midPan.SetBackgroundColour('green')

        vbox.Add(midPan,wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 20)

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10,5)
        st1=wx.StaticText(midPan,label='Black on green')
        st2=wx.StaticText(midPan,label='White on green')
        st2.SetForegroundColour('white')
        st3=wx.StaticText(midPan)
        st3.SetLabelMarkup("<span foreground='black' background='red'>Black on red</span>")
        st4=wx.StaticText(midPan)
        st4.SetLabelMarkup("<span foreground='white' background='red'>White on red</span>")

        sizer.Add(st1, pos=(1,1),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)
        sizer.Add(st2, pos=(2,2),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)
        sizer.Add(st3, pos=(3,3),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)
        sizer.Add(st4, pos=(4,1),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)

        midPan.SetSizer(sizer)
        pnl.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None,title="The Main Frame")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: what a mistake! Thanks very much Rolf! It works now...as a charm