# In addition to previous question wxPython grids

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

[wxPython gridbagsizer colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851853/wxpython-gridbagsizer-colour/60856618?noredirect=1#comment107671817_60856618)

Now the previous question was solved, i run into a new one: 
but now I can't change the text of the statusText item.

```
#Parent panel
pnl = wx.Panel(self)
pnl.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

midPan = wx.Panel(pnl)
midPan.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')

vbox.Add(midPan,wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 20)

sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10,5)
#sizer.
midPanelsT1=wx.StaticText(midPan,label='-- Checklist --')
sizer.Add(midPanelsT1, pos=(0,1),flag=wx.ALL,border=2)
```

When I add the def as follow:

def onStart(self,e):

```
    self.sb.SetStatusText('Counting processes',1)     
    count = 0
    for process in c.Win32_Process():
        count +=1
    self.sb.SetStatusText('Found '+str(count)+' running processes',1)
    self.midPanelsT1.SetLabel(str(count))
```

The label is not changing, while (str(count)) is around 300 process, which is shown in the sb How do I get back to my StatusText Items?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how you defined the statusbar, I assume that is what you are referring to, as you don't state that or show it in your code.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", size=(360,100)):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, size)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        pnl.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')
        btn = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_ANY, 'Start')

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        midPan = wx.Panel(pnl)
        midPan.SetBackgroundColour('green')

        self.sb = wx.StatusBar(self)
        self.sb.SetFieldsCount(2)
        self.SetStatusBar(self.sb)
        self.sb.SetStatusText('Counting processes',1)

        vbox.Add(midPan,wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 20)
        vbox.Add(btn,wx.ID_ANY, wx.ALL, 5)

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10,5)
        st1=wx.StaticText(midPan,label='Black on green')
        st2=wx.StaticText(midPan,label='White on green')
        st2.SetForegroundColour('white')
        st3=wx.StaticText(midPan)
        st3.SetLabelMarkup("<span foreground='black' background='red'>Black on red</span>")
        st4=wx.StaticText(midPan)
        st4.SetLabelMarkup("<span foreground='white' background='red'>White on red</span>")

        sizer.Add(st1, pos=(1,1),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)
        sizer.Add(st2, pos=(2,2),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)
        sizer.Add(st3, pos=(3,3),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)
        sizer.Add(st4, pos=(4,1),flag=wx.ALL,border=5)

        midPan.SetSizer(sizer)
        pnl.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onStart, btn)

        self.Show()

    def onStart(self,event):
        toggle = self.sb.GetStatusText(1)
        if toggle == 'Started....':
            self.sb.SetStatusText('Stopped....',1)
        else:
            self.sb.SetStatusText('Started....',1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None,title="The Main Frame")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]